# PHP file not running in CRON/CLI

Tags: php, cron

I have to run a php file every 5 seconds , and have two issues
 1. The file works perfectly when opened in a browser, but running the 'php myfile.php' command fails and produces the following error

```
    PHP Warning:  include_once(../tutadmin/config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '../tutadmin/config/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant TBL_USER - assumed 'TBL_USER' in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 5
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant TEACHER_USER_GROUP_ID - assumed 'TEACHER_USER_GROUP_ID' in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 9
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: current_user_id in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 14
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: current_date_time in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbc in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function Query() on null in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php:20
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 20
```

2. Crontab will not run the program every 5 seconds, only every minute at best.

Edit: the file does not work outside of cron in the CLI either, only on a web browser.. Cron is not the issue.

Comment: The file is called from another directory then the public html directory. So you have to set an include_path. But I think it's better to not run php but curl. To run every 5 seconds you can read more about 'workers'

Comment: `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/cron/teacher_status_cron.php on line 3` error is self explaining.  There is a problem in file path or permission.

Comment: About that second issue, for running a cron every 5 seconds, you should have multiple cron jobs on the same file, but with timeout. That is because cron is ment to run every minute (on its lowest scale). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks dennis!  please note that I said the file does exist (it runs fine in a webbrowser). Im running cron as www-data so I beleive it does have pernissions.

Comment: @dennis Can you please provide me an example of the syntax? At the noment I have * * * * * php file.php as the only line.. Cron logs show it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not right permissions on file, your cron can not open file, change permissions.

Comment: Do you know how exactly I can fix permissions? Im using cron as the www-data user. Dont really want to chown.

Comment: @Sam  check user for cron jobs and chown for that user, or fir more security you can create user for cron and after that chown fie that user(by default root user run cron)